# Homepage block doesn't hold to column count

Tags: cms-block, featured-product

I copied my list.phtml template to make a featured items block on my homepage. However all items in the category are displayed and not the column count that I set in my placement.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list-homepage.phtml" column_count="4" category_id="59"}}
```

Am I missing something?